# jupyter notebook justify text in markdown cells

Tags: css, markdown, jupyter-notebook, justify, text-justify

## Topic

Hey, i would like to use my Jupyter Notebooks for my Thesis. Therefore it would be nice to format the text within the markdown cells as justified text.

## Settings

I created the `{yourUser}/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`file with the follwoing settings: 
([more examples](https://github.com/titipata/customize_ipython_notebook/blob/master/custom.css))

```
.text_cell_render { /* Customize text cells */
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 145%;
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.CodeMirror pre { /* Customize code cells */
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

My Problem now is, that every setting of my css applies to my notebook except for the `text-align: justify;` and this also just in some parts.

## Example

Now my [test Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZb0.png) shows the strange behavior, that there is no justified text if i insert normal text just like that, but if i somehow format the text within an order the justification applies.

How can i make this work? Cheers!

Comment: and yes, i tried it with more lorem ipsum content

Comment: okay, it seems like you've to mark the text as text and put it in `<font>` your text `</font>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

`.text_cell_render p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}`

Apparently there is a rule in the notebook's CSS for `.rendered_html p` that overrides the settings for `.text_cell_render`.  The additional "p" tag makes the new rule specific enough to override the default.  See [this github thread](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2796).